# Variables/For Each in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, foreach

So I know I should have checked this before inserting but I did a sql insert that inserted the wrong date on several rows. The formula to correct this would be

`accounts.timely_date = accounts.due_date + 45 days 
where accounts.facility_id = 44`.

Is there any way to do this in sql for multiple rows at once?

Comment: What datatype is your accounts.timely_date and accounts.due_date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an UPDATE query:

```
update accounts
set
  timely_date = due_date + interval 45 day
where
  facility_id = 44
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL statement will update all rows in accounts table where facility_id = 44

```
update accounts
set timely_date = DATE_ADD(due_date,INTERVAL 45 DAY)
where facility_id = 44
```